# java creating a BufferedImage and taking a subimage from it

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I want to be able to get a BufferedImage from a URL / a File and then return a subimage from it. The first issue is that when i try it with

```
BufferedImage b = null;   
b = ImageIO.read("url");
```

b just stays null.

Can anyone explain to me how to successfully initialize a BufferedImage, so that I can then get a subimage of it using

```
BufferedImage c = b.getSubimage(0, 0, 20, 20);
```

Comment: Is your url really, `"url"`? You need to create a URL object, i.e., `URL url = new URL(pathToRealUrlOnTheInternet);`

Comment: i meant the filePath ( string object ) with "url" i didnt know how to express it that way though sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

I found it now by myself :^)
I just did this :

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
BufferedImage img2 = img.getSubimage(0,0,100,100);
```